# Subprocess.call() from external drive

Tags: python, windows, shell, cmd, subprocess

I'm trying to run a Python script off of an external drive. The script runs fine, but when it reaches the line `subprocess.call(callThis, shell=True)`, I get the error (from command prompt) `the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`. When I run the same script off of the C drive, it works fine and copies the files. Python is installed on the C drive, and the external drive is a microSD card if it matters. Python version is 3.4, but it needs to work on Python 2.7 as well.

Relevent code:

```
paths = [os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for dirpath, __, fnames in os.walk('.\\MUSIC') for fname in fnames]
for path in paths:
    pathcomp = path.replace('.\\MUSIC', 'C:\\redacted\\Music\\MUSIC')
    if not os.path.isfile(pathcomp):
        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        callThis = 'copy "'+abspath+'" "'+os.path.dirname(pathcomp)+'"'
        print(callThis)
        subprocess.call([callThis], shell=True)
```

printing `callThis` outputs something similar to

```
copy "G:\MUSIC\dir1\dir2\fname.mp3" "C:\redacted\Music\MUSIC\dir1\dir2\fname.mp3"
```

Typing that exact line into command prompt works fine and copies the file.

I think the problem has something to do with the command prompt running out of the C drive instead of the external drive. How can I make it run out of the external drive (show `G:/>` instead of `C:\` in the python script? I tried `subprocess.call('G:', shell=True) but have the same problem.

Comment: Try giving the absolute path to the copy command you're trying to run.

Comment: Absolute path to what? The program already gives the copy command absolute paths to the source file and destination.

Comment: What does "something similar to" mean exactly? How does it differ from what you showed there? If you have absolute paths to the files then *where* you run the command from doesn't matter. Is there a reason you are involving the "shell" here though? Would it not be simpler to just not do that and execute `copy` directly?

Comment: Windows has xcopy.exe and robocopy.exe (robust copy), but the `copy` command requires `shell=True`, which requires a command line string instead of an args list.

Comment: @cat40 I had meant the absolute path to the copy command. In linux you could use the command `which cp` and it would print the path to the actual cp command, which in most cases would be /bin/cp. The copy command you're using in windows lives somewhere in your windows file system and you should be able to give it an absolute path. Glad removing the list solved your problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a list to `subprocess.call` overrides the shell tokenization rules. You should pass a string to the `call` function instead.

```
subprocess.call(callThis,shell=True)
```